# Escape characters for PHP & SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

For the life of me, I cannot find any information how to use SimpleXML to parse with special characters.

I have some XML I am trying to parse, but PHP obviously doesn't like it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<calendar-multiget xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
  <D:prop>
    <D:getetag/>
    <calendar-data/>
  </D:prop>
  <D:href>/davical/caldav.php/rwr26/home/c9bfc6b0-064e-4316-83fe-753db34e67ee.ics</D:href>
  <D:href>/davical/caldav.php/rwr26/home/4e6e3500e89673.63357057.ics</D:href>
  <D:href>/davical/caldav.php/rwr26/home/4e6e42d394f9e5.08299254.ics</D:href>
</calendar-multiget>
```

I can't do `$D:href = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);`. And XPath isn't happy with that either, assuming I am doing this correctly. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't use special characters in your variable names, but you shouldn't need to. Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get the information contained between the <D:href> tags. I cannot change the XML itself, since it's part of a CalDav response from a Davical server.

Comment: Show us a little more of you using SimpleXMLElement to parse the example and where you're running into trouble and the messages you get. I'm going to assume the colon in the `$D:href` is at fault re: PHP happiness. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: And now it works (using relative paths and XPath). This after spending some lengthy time last night trying to get it to work. *facepalms* Right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), you'll see that putting a colon inside the variable name is not valid. But perhaps if you showed a little more we'd get a better picture of what's not working.

Comment: Fixed it. $xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<calendar-multiget xmlns:D=\"DAV:\" xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav\">
  <D:prop>
    <D:getetag/>
    <calendar-data/>
  </D:prop>
  <D:href>/davical/caldav.php/rwr26/home/c9bfc6b0-064e-4316-83fe-753db34e67ee.ics</D:href>
  <D:href>/davical/caldav.php/rwr26/home/4e6e3500e89673.63357057.ics</D:href>
  <D:href>/davical/caldav.php/rwr26/home/4e6e42d394f9e5.08299254.ics</D:href>
</calendar-multiget>
";


$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($root->xpath('//D:href') as $node) {
    echo $node . "<BR>";
}

Comment: Sorry to be wasting your time. PHP's XML stuff is somewhat foreign to me.

Answer (score 1):

Register the namespace with XPath [registerXPathNamespace](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php)